Are Duo Boons only available when initially activating a non-Trial Boon? Or can they be re-rolled for?
The Wiki's info on Duo Boons says that there's a 12% base chance when Melinoe has the right combinations of Boons, but nothing about how Changes of Fate affect those chances.
So, is the obvious way for me to tilt the odds in my favor of any use for the moment of activation? Or am I stuck with just equipping The Queen Arcana Card?
